# Clang IfStmt with shortcut binary operator in condition

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I am trying to detect if there is a function call inside an if statement as part of condition; like following:

```
if (cmp(a, b)){
  \\do something
}
I have found I could do this with AST matcher in following manner:
Matcher.addMatcher(ifStmt(hasCondition(callExpr().bind("call_expr")))
                           .bind("call_if_stmt"),&handleMatch);
```

But the problem is condition could have shortcuts like &&, ||; like following:

```
if(a != b && cmp(a,b) || c == 10){
\\ do something
}
```

Now this condition has binaryoperator && and ||; also have a call expression as part of it. Now how I could detect that there is a call expression inside this if statement? Definitely I don't know how many binary operator as shortcuts will be there, so I am looking for a generalize solution for this, possibly using clange AST matcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, `if(cmp(a,b))`, the CallExpr node is a direct child of the IfStmt. In the second case, it is a descendant of the IfStmt, but not a child. Instead, it is nested beneath two BinaryOperator nodes. (I found this out by looking at the AST with `clang-check -ast-dump test.cpp --`.) Adding a `hasDescendant` traversal matcher will find the more deeply nested CallExpr. Unfortunately, that alone will not find the first case. So we could use `anyOf` to combine it with the original matcher:

```
ifStmt( 
  hasCondition( 
    anyOf(
      callExpr().bind("top_level_call_expr"),
      hasDescendant(
        callExpr().bind("nested_call_expr")
      )
    )
  )
).bind("call_if_stmt")
```

If I take test.cpp to have the following code:

```
bool cmp(int a, int b){return a < b;}

int f(int a, int c){
  int b = 42;
  if( a != b && cmp(a,b) || c == 10){
    return 2;
  }
  return c;
}

int g(int a, int c){
  int b = 42;
  if( cmp(a,b)) {
    return 2;
  }
  return c;
}
```

then I can test this with `clang-query test.cpp --`:

```
clang-query> let m2 ifStmt( hasCondition( anyOf(callExpr().bind("top_level_call_expr"),hasDescendant(callExpr().bind("nested_call_expr"))))).bind("call_if_stmt")
clang-query> m m2

Match #1:

/path/to/test.xpp:5:7: note: "call_if_stmt" binds here
      if( a != b && cmp(a,b) || c == 10){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/to/test.cpp:5:21: note: "nested_call_expr" binds here
      if( a != b && cmp(a,b) || c == 10){
                    ^~~~~~~~
/path/to/test.cpp:5:7: note: "root" binds here
      if( a != b && cmp(a,b) || c == 10){
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

/path/to/test.cpp:13:7: note: "call_if_stmt" binds here
      if( cmp(a,b)) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/to/test.cpp:13:7: note: "root" binds here
      if( cmp(a,b)) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/to/test.cpp:13:11: note: "top_level_call_expr" binds here
      if( cmp(a,b)) {
          ^~~~~~~~
2 matches.
```

Comment: That is really great, is it also possible to if I have more than one call inside if statement, I could count them; I mean I could count how many call expression there inside if statement?

Comment: I got the answer: 
  
  ifStmt(hasCondition(forEachDescendant(callExpr().bind("call_expression")))).bind("if_stmt_inside_call")